# Unable to get div containing router-outlet to flex with flex-layout library

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

I am having a play with angular flex-layout on an angular 6 cli generated project and am having a hard time getting a router-outlet to fill available height in a column layout.

In my root app component markup I have the following:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
  <app-header-bar></app-header-bar>
  <div fxFlexFill>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</div>
```

which renders as:

[image]

The div containing my router-outlet is not filling all available space as I end up with whitespace as per the yellow shaded area on the image above.

I have tried apply `height:100%` to the `html` and `body` elements, but this make no difference.

I have used angular-material in an older angular 1.x project before, so am familiar with the typical flex attribute approach they use, but I must admit I have found the flex-layout library a bit more challenging to get working.

Has anyone else faced similar issues? I feel like I have missed something obvious!

Thanks

Comment: What version of flex-layout are you using

Comment: @Paulie_D OP seems to be using Angular, not AngularJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlexFill>
  <app-header-bar></app-header-bar>
  <div fxFlex>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
</div>
```

**styles.scss**

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

it should work as long as column is a direct child of body. If not please make a codepen or something where we can see something.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This suggestion is correct as fxLayout="column" will make parent container to be flex container and then fxFlex will work on the child element